# When to use separate PPAs?

Tags: ppa, packaging

I'm interested in setting up PPAs for a few projects that I'm working on, and I'm trying to find out how many PPAs I need.  Should I create one PPA for each project, effectively having a single package in each?   The fact that the name is "**personal** package archive" and the fact that they're created under my launchpad username make it seem like I should have all of my projects in one PPA - would that cause problems?  What if it's multiple similar/related packages, such as unity lenses?

The [instructions](https://help.launchpad.net/Packaging/PPA) don't really say anything about how much to put in a single PPA, though they do indicate having more than one is okay.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to create multiple PPAs, unless it's necessary. For example, daily builds, and stable releases, of the same project (same package) would need to be separate PPAs, since you can't have multiple versions of the same package, in a single archive. However, just making packages of various things you find an interest in, or as a point of staging packages you wish to propose for inclusion in the Ubuntu or Debian archives, does not require multiple PPAs.

The best thing you can do is organize in a way that minimizes any potential damage to users' systems who decide to add your PPA. Packaging of libraries and applications that exist in Ubuntu already, can greatly increase potential for damage, especially if you start adding extra patches and such.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say its dependent on a use case and how the projects are related to each other.  If you have numerous projects separate from each other, then use different PPAs for each.  If they're all related to each other, use one PPA.

Comment: what would you use as a measure of related-ness?  Actual dependencies?

Comment: That's what I'd say.  For example, if Project2 depended on all parts of Project1 to be installed, and Project2 is just a different front-end to Project1, then include Project2 in Project1's PPA as a different package name.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at tualatrix PPA's you will see there is a package for every project:

https://launchpad.net/~tualatrix

lists the following

> Personal package archives

```
PPA for Software Center
PPA named daily for Ding Zhou
GIMP
Fcitx Gimpanel
GNOME Shell
GNOME Terminal with Google Search Support
iBentu PPA
libnotify
MeeGo
Nautilus
Tualatrix's Next PPA
PPA for Personal Use
Ubuntu Tweak Stable PPA
VPN Indicator
Wayland Unofficial PPA
```

I would say: 1 PPA for 1 project.